# Do wolf kills count towards the looting enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It is a fairly well known bug that if you throw a splash potion of harming at a mob and then switch your main hand back to a looting sword then the enchantment will apply to the mob drops despite never hitting the mob with the actual sword. Does this also work with other forms of deaths? Specifically does it count when your tamed wolf kills a skeleton while you are holding a looting sword? The wolf will attack the skeleton without the player having to prompt it by attacking the skeleton first. Despite this as far as I know this will still count as a "player kill", though it won't add to your kill statistic for that mob. Will the kill also count as far as the looting enchantment is concerned?

Comment: Should be easy to test.

Comment: The answer is "no".

Comment: Interestingly, looting halves the number of bows dropped by skeletons...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Looting does not apply to wolf kills.